# Confusion about return statements python

Tags: python, return

I'm just starting to learn Python, and I don't understand the difference between the indentation of the return statements in the code below.

```
def list_1(students, number):
    for i in students: 
        if i == number: 
           return True
    return False

def list_1(students, number):
    for i in students: 
        if i == number: 
           return True
        else: 
           return False
```

For the first code, if the input number is found in the students list, then it returns True, but in the second code even if the number is found in the students list, it returns False.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate (I've seen this *exact* code before), but the short answer is: The latter *always* returns for the first item, the former only returns `False` if *none* of the items pass.

Comment: Why is the first line inside the function indented to the same level as the function declaration itself?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for your reply, but I don't understand why. For the second code, it is an if-else statement, so when the 'if' statement passes shouldn't the output be True? Why does it move on to the 'else' statement and output False.

Comment: @SamL: If the *first* element *doesn't* equal `number`, you'll immediately `return False` because the `else:` executes, and the loop never has a chance to continue. The first loop only returns early if it finds an element equal to `number`, the second *always* returns "early" based on the comparison with the very first element of `students`.

Answer (score 0):

The second function will execute loop operations only once. It tests the first element of the list and then return the result of the first comparison. Your function behaves like that:

```
def list_1(students, number):
    if students[0] == number: 
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

you have this behavior because `return` statement returns a value and breaks out the function.